# Need to rename data in a column, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that grabs all the data from a given table, but there are a few data points that need to be renamed.

Ex: 
in my objects column i have thing1, thing2, thing3, and they need to be renamed to thing0, thing1, thing2,

Here is my query where i tried to rename just one piece of data

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE project LIKE "mine"
UPDATE objects
SET objects='thing0'
WHERE objects='thing1'
```

Thank You.

Comment: Your question is very generic and will thus attract generic answers. Try providing a schema, so that we know what we're dealing with.

Comment: Did you try it? Were there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your post is very generic and will hardly attract any answers that will straight-up solve your problem. In this answer, I'll try to set you on track by letting you know what you've done wrong.

For starters, your query is wrong, which is something you can pretty easily figure out using any [SQL syntax checking tool](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/). What you're trying to do with it is still not quite clear to me, but what is clear is that you have mingled together two separate queries into one badly. The queries are:

1. `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE project LIKE "mine";`
2. `UPDATE objects SET objects = 'thing0' WHERE objects = 'thing1';`

By separating the above queries, it's easy to see that they aren't related at all, which is an indication that your thinking has been wrong. In the first query, you select all rows of the table `my_table` whose `project` attribute is the word `'mine'`, whereas in the second query, you update the `objects` column of the table `objects` to `'thing0'` for the rows that have the `objects` column set to `'thing1'`. You can see that this doesn't make any sense.

If what you are trying to do is to update the `objects` column of the table `my_table` to `'thing0'` for the rows the column has the value `'thing1'` and the `project` contains the word `'mine'`, then the query you need is something along the following lines:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET objects = 'thing0'
WHERE objects = 'thing1'
AND project LIKE '%mine%';
```

In the above query, note the `%` wildcard sign around the word `'mine'`. Here's a short guide as to how you can use it based on your needs:

```sql
AND project LIKE 'mine'     -- Finds any values that equal "mine" (AND project = 'mine')
AND project LIKE 'mine%'    -- Finds any values that start with "mine"
AND project LIKE '%mine'    -- Finds any values that end with "mine"
AND project LIKE '%mine%'   -- Finds any values that have "mine" in any position
```

Comment: Yes i am trying to do both those commands at once, retrieving the data as well as renaming the parts of the data that need renaming. If this cannot be done in one sql statement then my thinking was wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help @victorz22  Indeed, you can't use one statement to both extract the data and update the table. The query I provided you in my answer will update your table based on the criteria you pass. It's up to you then to either select the data before or after the update.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use an update as follows...

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET `objects` = 'thing0' WHERE `objects` = 'thing1' AND `project` LIKE '%mine%';
```